# GLSL - optimize if-else

Tags: if-statement, glsl, shader

I have GLSL mobile shader (ES 2.0) and inside I have this:

```
float b = texture2D(t, texCoord).r;
float s = 0.0;
if (b > 240.0) s = b - 2322.2;
else if (b > 90.0) s = b - 74.0;    
else if (b < 10.0) s = b / 10.0;
else s = b - 10.0;
```

Is it going to be slow? I know, that branching in shader should be avoided.
Is there any way, how to rewrite this to remove ifs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use the GLSL functions [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) and [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml).

[`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) interpolates between 2 values according to a floating point interpolation value `a` in the range [0.0, 1.0]. If the `a` is equal 0.0 then the 1st value is returned and if the `a` is equal 1.0 then the 2nd value is returned.

[`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) tests whether a value is less than an edge value. If it is less then 0.0 is returned, else 1.0 is returned.

If you combine the 2 functions your code will look like this:

```
float b = texture2D(t, texCoord).r;
float s = mix(
    mix( b/10.0, b-10.0,   step(10.0, b) ),
    mix( b-74.0, b-2322.2, step(240.0, b) ),
    step(90.0, b) );
```

Note, the result of [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) is either exactly 0.0 or exactly 1.0, this causes that [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) either returns the 1st value or returns the 2nd value.

Comment: From my experience using `step` and `mix` has *always* been **slower** even when "stepping" on uniforms, your code needs to always execute *all* operations leaving only the two lerps that *could* be optimized, while OPs original code has the chance of only executing one operation. Putting that aside for a moment though, I think the correct answer here should be "profile on target hardware and optimize if necessary", even though I highly suspect this to be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Because this is for a mobile shader, I dont have all possible target devices.